# Scaling images generated by imshow

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

The following code snippet

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(100).reshape((10,10))
arr2 = np.arange(25).reshape((5,5))

fig, (ax1, ax2, ) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(3,5))
ax1.imshow(arr1, interpolation="none")
ax2.imshow(arr2, interpolation="none")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

produces two images with the same size, but a much lower "pixel density" in the second one.

[image]

I would like to have the second image plotted at the same scale (i.e. pixel density) of the first, without filling the subfigure, possibly correctly aligned (i.e. the origin of the image in the same subplot position as the first one.)

**Edit**

The shapes of `arr1` and `arr2` are only an example to show the problem. What I'm looking for is a way to ensure that two different images generated by `imshow` in different portions of the figure are drawn at exactly the same scale.

Comment: What about just interpolating your 2d-matrices before plotting? There should be many methods in scipy or scikit-image. The latter should be easier to use because of ready-to-use [resize](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.resize) operations.

Comment: @sascha I need that the second plot (which has less pixels) is rendered smaller than the first one, so that the xy scales of both pictures are equal.  BTW I'm plotting data, not images, so it is important that the individual "pixels" remain visible with their approximate coordinates. Also a solution based on `pcolormesh` is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing I could think of didn't work, but `gridspec` does. The origins here aren't aligned explicitly, it just takes advantage of how gridspec fills rows (and there's an unused subplot as a spacer).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import gridspec

sizes = (10, 5)
arr1 = np.arange(sizes[0]*sizes[0]).reshape((sizes[0],sizes[0]))
arr2 = np.arange(sizes[1]*sizes[1]).reshape((sizes[1],sizes[1]))


# Maybe sharex, sharey? No, we pad one and lose data in the other
#fig, (ax1, ax2, ) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(3,5), sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(3,5))

# wspace so the unused lower-right subplot doesn't squeeze lower-left
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 2, height_ratios = [sizes[0], sizes[1]], wspace = 0.0)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,:])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])


ax1.imshow(arr1, interpolation="none")
ax2.imshow(arr2, interpolation="none")

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The solution is OK, after the edit. I'm sorry but I missed your edit, my comment applies to the first solution, and I will delete it.